# If statement to check boolean value of in "RectangleToRectangle" Javascript using the phaser 3 library

Tags: javascript, if-statement, boolean, phaser-framework

Okay i'm using the phaser 3 library to build a small game. In this game an user has to place game elements on a specific place on the screen. If all the elements are in the correct place one point should be added. If they are not the game resets to previous state.

I have the underlying code:

First to get the Bounds of the objects

```
var bounds_po_orderid = this.answer_element_po_orderid.getBounds();
var bounds_po_eventid = this.answer_element_po_eventid.getBounds();
var bounds_po_orderdate = this.answer_element_po_orderdate.getBounds();
...............
```

Second compare if the different bounds intersect:

```
var overl_answerzone_one_bounds_po_orderid  = Phaser.Geom.Intersects.RectangleToRectangle(bounds_po_orderid, bounds_answerzone_one);
var overl_answerzone_one_bounds_po_eventid  = Phaser.Geom.Intersects.RectangleToRectangle(bounds_po_eventid, bounds_answerzone_one);
var overl_answerzone_one_bounds_po_orderdate  = Phaser.Geom.Intersects.RectangleToRectangle(bounds_po_orderdate, bounds_answerzone_one);
var overl_answerzone_one_bounds_po_line_purchaseorderid = Phaser.Geom.Intersects.RectangleToRectangle(bounds_po_line_purchaseorderid, bounds_answerzone_one);
```

And check if the true/false value when a button is pressed:

```
this.input.on("gameobjectdown", function (pointer, gameObject) 
    {
        if (gameObject.name == "check_answer_button") 
        {
            if (overl_answerzone_one_bounds_po_orderid ===  true && 
              overl_answerzone_one_bounds_po_eventid === false && 
              overl_answerzone_one_bounds_po_orderdate === false && 
              overl_answerzone_one_bounds_po_line_purchaseorderid === false && 
              overl_answerzone_one_bounds_po_line_orderlineid === false 
             ) 
            {
                this.count = 1
                eventsCenter.emit('update-count', this.count)
            }
            else
            {
                // reset all the controls
            }
```

The code above doesn't work. For some reason when the first element is in the correct place it doesn't matter where the rest of the elements is placed it will say that the if statement can be fired. I tried replacing the "===" with "==". No result. So basically I don't know what i'm doing wrong.

Comment: where are you checking for the intersection, in the `update` function? where is the `gameobjectdown` eventlistener set, in the `create` function? Or better still can you maybe share more code, stripped down to the basic?

Comment: I apologize for the late response, something came up. But your comment steered me in the right direction. The code was in the wrong place and I adjusted it. @winner_joiner: to my knowledge I cannot 'give you a correct' answer in the comments section. But I placed part of the code in a seperate function and everything works correctly now.

Comment: no problem, just glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is all the relevant code you need to check that the other elements are in fact in the right spots too.

Right now you are only checking that the first element is in the first answer zone and that none of the other elements are there.

If you have different answer zonen for the other elements you need to check that they are in their right answer zone.

Comment: Thanks for you comment. The other answer zones are also in the code but the copy/paste would be very long. The comment given by @winner_joiner directed me in the solution. I place part of the code in a seperate function which I now call from the create() function.